# Eclipse Launch Group: Stop if single launch configuration fails

Tags: eclipse, maven

We are having Maven projects relying on each other, which are built separately and included as dependencies. So to have a single button to compile all the intermediate steps, I use Eclipse Launch Groups. However when a single build fails, the Launch Group just goes on, which can be unrecognizable unless you control every single console instance.

Is there a way to stop the execution if a single step fails? Maybe Launch Groups are not the perfect fit and there is another tool for multiple Run Configuration executions?

Comment: I know that the projects could be restructured as Maven modules, but that would be a lot of work for so little gain, especially as we would have to restructure the used profiles (currently different Maven Run Configurations use differen profiles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By try-and-error I found the following solution, which works for our Maven builds: Chose as "Post launch action" "Wait for console output", and let it wait for "[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS". This pauses the execution of the launch group at the failed process, pointing you directly to the first occured error.

If you use other build setups or tools you have to check which string gets exclusively printed on build success.